# Make sentence from value of dictionary

Tags: python, list, dictionary, for-loop

link for original txt file
https://medusa.ugent.be/en/exercises/187053144/description/wM6YaQUbWdHKPhQX/media/ICD.txt

This is what I got:

```
given_string = 'You are what you eat.'
dictionary ={'D89.1': 'Cryoglobulinemia', 'M87.332': 'Other secondary osteonecrosis of left radius', 'M25.57': 'Pain in ankle and joints of foot', 'H59.111': 'Intraoperative hemorrhage and hematoma of right eye and adnexa complicating an ophthalmic procedure', 'I82.5Z9': 'Chronic embolism and thrombosis of unspecified deep veins of unspecified distal lower extremity', 'T38.3X': 'Poisoning by, adverse effect of and underdosing of insulin and oral hypoglycemic [antidiabetic] drugs', 'H95.52': 'Postprocedural hematoma of ear and mastoid process following other procedure', 'Q90.1': 'Trisomy 21, mosaicism (mitotic nondisjunction)', 'X83.8': 'Intentional self-harm by other specified means', 'H02.145': 'Spastic ectropion of left lower eyelid', 'M67.341': 'Transient synovitis, right hand', 'P07.32': 'Preterm newborn, gestational age 29 completed weeks', 'R44.8': 'Other symptoms and signs involving general sensations and perceptions', 'R03.1': 'Nonspecific low blood-pressure reading', 'Q03': 'Congenital hydrocephalus', 'C11.0': 'Malignant neoplasm of superior wall of nasopharynx', 'C44.4': 'Other and unspecified malignant neoplasm of skin of scalp and neck', 'N48.5': 'Ulcer of penis', 'T50.2X1': 'Poisoning by carbonic-anhydrase inhibitors, benzothiadiazides and other diuretics, accidental (unintentional)', 'V92.13': 'Drowning and submersion due to being thrown overboard by motion of other powered watercraft', 'D30.0': 'Benign neoplasm of kidney', 'M08.06': 'Unspecified juvenile rheumatoid arthritis, knee', 'T41.5X4': 'Poisoning by therapeutic gases, undetermined', 'T59.3X2': 'Toxic effect of lacrimogenic gas, intentional self-harm', 'S84.91': 'Injury of unspecified nerve at lower leg level, right leg', 'Z80.4': 'Family history of malignant neoplasm of genital organs', 'M05.34': 'Rheumatoid heart disease with rheumatoid arthritis of hand', 'Y36.531': 'War operations involving thermal radiation effect of nuclear weapon, civilian', 'H59.88': 'Other intraoperative complications of eye and adnexa, not elsewhere classified', 'R29.91': 'Unspecified symptoms and signs involving the musculoskeletal system', 'M71.139': 'Other infective bursitis, unspecified wrist', 'S00.441': 'External constriction of right ear', 'V04': 'Pedestrian injured in collision with heavy transport vehicle or bus', 'C92.1': 'Chronic myeloid leukemia, BCR/ABL-positive', 'I82.60': 'Acute embolism and thrombosis of unspecified veins of upper extremity', 'I75.89': 'Atheroembolism of other site', 'S51.031': 'Puncture wound without foreign body of right elbow', 'Z01.110': 'Encounter for hearing examination following failed hearing screening', 'I06.8': 'Other rheumatic aortic valve diseases', 'Z68.25': 'Body mass index (BMI) 25.0-25.9, adult', 'A66': 'Yaws', 'S78.921': 'Partial traumatic amputation of right hip and thigh, level unspecified', 'F44': 'Dissociative and conversion disorders', 'O87.8': 'Other venous complications in the puerperium', 'K04.3': 'Abnormal hard tissue formation in pulp', 'V38.7': 'Person on outside of three-wheeled motor vehicle injured in noncollision transport accident in traffic accident', 'V36.1': 'Passenger in three-wheeled motor vehicle injured in collision with other nonmotor vehicle in nontraffic accident', 'B94.9': 'Sequelae of unspecified infectious and parasitic disease', 'K50.911': "Crohn's disease, unspecified, with rectal bleeding", 'S00.52': 'Blister (nonthermal) of lip and oral cavity', 'T43.1': 'Poisoning by, adverse effect of and underdosing of monoamine-oxidase-inhibitor antidepressants', 'B99.8': 'Other infectious disease', 'S97.12': 'Crushing injury of lesser toe(s)', 'S02.69': 'Fracture of mandible of other specified site', 'V29.10': 'Motorcycle passenger injured in collision with unspecified motor vehicles in nontraffic accident', 'Z68.35': 'Body mass index (BMI) 35.0-35.9, adult', 'A81.2': 'Progressive multifocal leukoencephalopathy', 'V44.4': 'Person boarding or alighting a car injured in collision with heavy transport vehicle or bus', 'M62.51': 'Muscle wasting and atrophy, not elsewhere classified, shoulder', 'M62.151': 'Other rupture of muscle (nontraumatic), right thigh', 'V52.2': 'Person on outside of pick-up truck or van injured in collision with two- or three-wheeled motor vehicle in nontraffic accident', 'E09.622': 'Drug or chemical induced diabetes mellitus with other skin ulcer', 'S43.492': 'Other sprain of left shoulder joint', 'M08.212': 'Juvenile rheumatoid arthritis with systemic onset, left shoulder', 'R00.0': 'Tachycardia, unspecified', 'G21.8': 'Other secondary parkinsonism', 'W58.01': 'Bitten by alligator', 'D46.1': 'Refractory anemia with ring sideroblasts', 'H61.32': 'Acquired stenosis of external ear canal secondary to inflammation and infection', 'H95.0': 'Recurrent cholesteatoma of postmastoidectomy cavity', 'Z72.4': 'Inappropriate diet and eating habits', 'Z68.41': 'Body mass index (BMI) 40.0-44.9, adult', 'S20.172': 'Other superficial bite of breast, left breast', 'I63.232': 'Cerebral infarction due to unspecified occlusion or stenosis of left carotid arteries', 'M14.811': 'Arthropathies in other specified diseases classified elsewhere, right shoulder', 'E13.41': 'Other specified diabetes mellitus with diabetic mononeuropathy', 'H02.53': 'Eyelid retraction', 'V95.49': 'Other spacecraft accident injuring occupant', 'D74.0': 'Congenital methemoglobinemia', 'D60.1': 'Transient acquired pure red cell aplasia', 'T52.1X2': 'Toxic effect of benzene, intentional self-harm', 'O71.2': 'Postpartum inversion of uterus', 'M08.439': 'Pauciarticular juvenile rheumatoid arthritis, unspecified wrist', 'M01.X72': 'Direct infection of left ankle and foot in infectious and parasitic diseases classified elsewhere', 'H95.3': 'Accidental puncture and laceration of ear and mastoid process during a procedure', 'C74.92': 'Malignant neoplasm of unspecified part of left adrenal gland', 'G00': 'Bacterial meningitis, not elsewhere classified', 'M19.011': 'Primary osteoarthritis, right shoulder', 'G72.49': 'Other inflammatory and immune myopathies, not elsewhere classified', 'Z68.34': 'Body mass index (BMI) 34.0-34.9, adult', 'V86.64': 'Passenger of military vehicle injured in nontraffic accident', 'L20.9': 'Atopic dermatitis, unspecified', 'S65.51': 'Laceration of blood vessel of other and unspecified finger', 'B67.1': 'Echinococcus granulosus infection of lung', 'S08.81': 'Traumatic amputation of nose', 'Z36.5': 'Encounter for antenatal screening for isoimmunization', 'S59.22': 'Salter-Harris Type II physeal fracture of lower end of radius', 'M66.359': 'Spontaneous rupture of flexor tendons, unspecified thigh', 'I69.919': 'Unspecified symptoms and signs involving cognitive functions following unspecified cerebrovascular disease', 'I25.700': 'Atherosclerosis of coronary artery bypass graft(s), unspecified, with unstable angina pectoris', 'V24.0': 'Motorcycle driver injured in collision with heavy transport vehicle or bus in nontraffic accident', 'S53.025': 'Posterior dislocation of left radial head', 'Q72.819': 'Congenital shortening of unspecified lower limb', 'G44.82': 'Headache associated with sexual activity', 'M93.2': 'Osteochondritis dissecans', 'V44.6': 'Car passenger injured in collision with heavy transport vehicle or bus in traffic accident', 'O90.89': 'Other complications of the puerperium, not elsewhere classified', 'T83.518': 'Infection and inflammatory reaction due to other urinary catheter', 'Z02.9': 'Encounter for administrative examinations, unspecified', 'S55.091': 'Other specified injury of ulnar artery at forearm level, right arm'}
```

Each character of the string must be replaced by randomly choosing among all possible Hippocrates-codes that encode the character, and return result contain code where character is in, and index of character in value

so. this is the answer that I supposed to get

```
A66.0 M62.51.29 V44.6.68 H95.3.70 M08.06.26 S51.031.39 V92.13.17 V95.49.25 P07.32.46 C11.0.44 V04.45 E13.41.30 G21.8.5 R00.0.4 V52.2.54 B67.1.38 V24.0.43 M01.X72.10 C74.92.35 G72.49.35 Z68.41.24
```

and, this is the answer that i got.

```
F44.6.4 S78.922.3 W36.1.17 S93.121.2 E10.32.39 A00.1.12 S90.464.3 T37.1X.9 T43.2.17 W24.0.3 Q60.3.5 V59.9.14 S66.911.5 W93.42 V14.1.34 Y92.139.14 T21.06.12 T65.89.6 Q95.3.4 S85.161.16 S93.121.7 T37.1X.18 V49.60.23 T37.1X5.7 F98.29.16 J10.89.14
```

for get that I wrote code like this

```
import re
import random
class Hippocrates:
def __init__(self, code):
    self.code = code
def description(self, x):
    line_list = []
    split_point = []
    k = []
    v = []
    with open(self.code) as f:
        for line in f:
            for i in line:
                if i == " ":
                    split_point.append(line.find(i))

    with open(self.code) as f:
        for line in f:
            line_list.append(line.rstrip())
    for i in line_list:
        a = i.split(" ", 1)
        k.append(a[0])
        v.append(a[1])
    d  = dict(zip(k, v))
    for key, value in d.items():
        if x == key:
            return d[key]

    else:

        raise ValueError('invalid ICD-code')
def character(self, numb):

    line_list = []
    split_point = []
    k = []
    v = []
    with open(self.code) as f:
        for line in f:
            for i in line:
                if i == " ":
                    split_point.append(line.find(i))

    with open(self.code) as f:
        for line in f:
            line_list.append(line.rstrip())
    for i in line_list:
        a = i.split(" ", 1)
        k.append(a[0])
        v.append(a[1])
    d = dict(zip(k, v))

    rev = numb[::-1]
    revs = rev.split('.',1)
    r1 =(revs[1][::-1])
    r2 = (revs[0][::-1])
    for key, value in d.items():
        if r1 == key:
            answer =  d[key]
            result = answer[int(r2)]
            return result

    else:

        raise ValueError('invalid Hippocrates-code')

def codes(self, char):

    line_list = []
    split_point = []
    k = []
    v = []
    r_v = []
    code_result = []
    des_result  = []
    des_result2 = []
    location = []
    final = []
    with open(self.code) as f:
        for line in f:
            for i in line:
                if i == " ":
                    split_point.append(line.find(i))

    with open(self.code) as f:
        for line in f:
            line_list.append(line.rstrip())
    for i in line_list:
        a = i.split(" ", 1)
        k.append(a[0])
        v.append(a[1])
    d = dict(zip(k, v))

    for i in v:
        for x in i:
            if x == char:
                r_v.append(i)

    for key, value in d.items():
        for i in r_v:
            if i == value:
                code_result.append(key)
    for key in d.keys():
        for i in code_result:
            if i == key:

                des_result.append(d[i])
    for i in des_result:
        if i not in des_result2:
            des_result2.append(i)
    for i in des_result2:
        regex = re.escape(char)
        a = [m.start() for m in re.finditer(regex,i)]
        location.append(a)
    location = (sum(location,[]))
    for i in range(len(code_result)):
        answer =  (str(code_result[i]) +'.'+ str(location[i]))
        final.append(answer)
    return (set(final))

def encode(self, plaintxt):

    line_list = []
    split_point = []
    #key of dictionary
    k = []
    #value of dictionary
    v = []
    #description that contain character with index
    r = []
    #list of possible choice
    t = []
    #randomly choosen result from t
    li_di = []
    #descriptoin
    des = []
    #index of char in description
    index_char = []
    #answer to print
    resul = []
    dictlist = []
    answers =  []
    with open(self.code) as f:
        for line in f:
            for i in line:
                if i == " ":
                    split_point.append(line.find(i))

    with open(self.code) as f:
        for line in f:
            line_list.append(line.rstrip())
    for i in line_list:
        a = i.split(" ", 1)
        k.append(a[0])
        v.append(a[1])
    d = dict(zip(k, v))
    print(d)

    for key, value in d.items():
        for i in plaintxt:
            if i in value:
                answer = d[key] +':'+ str(d[key].index(i))
                r.append(answer)
    print(r)
    a = len(plaintxt)
    b=0
    for i in range(len(r)):
        t.append(r[b::a])
        b+=1
        if b == len(plaintxt):
            break
    for i in t:
        li_di.append(random.choice(i))

    for i in li_di:
        sep = i.split(":", 1)
        des.append(sep[0])
        index_char.append(sep[1])
    print(index_char)
    for i in des:
        for key, value in d.items():
            if i == value:
                resul.append(key)
    print(resul)


    for i in range(len(resul)):
        answers.append(resul[i]+'.'+index_char[i]+'')

    return(" ".join(answers))
```

the codes that represent character in given_string should be in same order with, original given string, but i messed it up. how can i fix this?

Comment: What do you mean by: *Hippocrates-codes that encode the character* ?

Comment: Also if you are incorporating random choices into this code, how are you expecting to get a consistent answer each time?

Comment: It means that I need to find each character of given_string from dictionary that represnet Hippocrates-codes, from value of dictionary I need to check out that character of give string is involved in value or not. then if it is in value get key and index of character in value. it is O.K to get diff answer as long as I get location of the character in dictionary.

ex)

given_string = 'o'
dictionary ={'D89.1': 'Cryoglobulinemia'}

answer should be either D89.1.3 or D89.1.6

Comment: Can you point us to where _exactly_ the issue is? Such as is the character index wrong? Is it getting the wrong code?

Comment: Or are you saying that you are correctly matching characters to valid codes, but the order of the output is not being preserved so that the elements correspond correctly?

Comment: Or are you saying that you are correctly matching characters to valid codes, but the order of the output is not being preserved so that the elements correspond correctly?
<===
this is what I want to say Thank you

Comment: Ah ok I get it now. Let me try running this and see if I can figure out what the issue is

Comment: just uploaed full code that I made. I'm working on encode part thanks for your help

Comment: No problem and is the `self.code` file just a file containing the dictionary you provided? If so could you provide that file as well so I can be sure that I'm running your code the exact same way you are

Comment: no it is a just class method for  ___init___ i will add up link for the original online txt.file

Comment: I mean this here: `with open(self.code) as f`, you're using it like a file so I'm wondering what I should pass in to the init function

Comment: textfile should pass through init function

Comment: got it, also I think you may have forgotten to actually include the link as it's just regular text

Comment: sorry just added it

Comment: So my best guess is that you are relying on the order to be preserved in Python's dictionaries, which isn't always the case, but there are a lot of other things going on here so I'm slowly trying to figure out what the issue might be. Do you mind if I try reworking a different solution (but to accomplish the same result)?

Comment: Sure, I'm also trying other way to solve this.

Comment: Ok sounds good, this is actually a pretty interesting problem. By the way, does the case of the character matter, or should I treat everything as case-insensitive?

Comment: case of character matter.

Comment: also, all the special characters and space need to be found in value of dictionary.

Comment: sounds good, and if every single character isn't found then should some error be thrown?

Comment: also are you considering only the first index of each character in a particular value, or all of the indices of a character in a particular value

Comment: Yes, value error should be raised for that case, and for the second question, I'm considering all of the indices of a character in particular value, but that condition has not mentioned in problem, so I'm not really sure.

Comment: Ok I think I have a working solution, I just posted an answer. It takes into account the `ValueError` as well as multiple indices in a single value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work for your `encode` function:

```
def encode(self, plaintxt):
    code_map = {}
    codes = []
    with open(self.code) as f:
        for line in f:
            line = line.rstrip().split(' ', 1)
            code_map[line[0]] = line[1]

    for ch in plaintxt:
        matches = []
        for key, value in code_map.items():
            pos = -1
            while True:
                pos = value.find(ch, pos + 1)
                if pos != -1:
                    matches.append((key, pos))
                else:
                    break

        if not matches:
            raise ValueError(f'Character {ch} cannot be encoded as there are no matches')

        code_tuple = random.choice(matches)
        code, idx = code_tuple
        codes.append(f'{code}.{idx}')

    return ' '.join(codes)
```

**Edit**: I updated this to make it more space-efficient, by getting rid of `char_map` and appending codes as it goes

First, it creates a dict of keys as codes and values as the corresponding strings. Then it iterates through the given `plaintxt` string, and searches all of the values of the dict for matches (including multiple matches in a single value), and adds this to a `matches` list of tuples, where each tuple contains a suitable code and the index of the match. If there are no matches, it raises a `ValueError` as soon as it runs into an issue. It chooses randomly from each list of tuples to choose some code and index pair, and appends this to a list on the fly, and then at the end it joins this list to make your encoded string.

Comment: @goldenasian btw I just made an update that makes it more space-efficient, if you want to use that version instead

Comment: Think this one is perfect answer! thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: @goldenasian no problem, it was actually a pretty interesting problem to work out

Comment: @ awarrier99 and the explanation was really easy to understand thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If memory is not a problem, I think you should build an index of possible choices of each character from the dictionary. Here is an example code:

```
import random

def build_char_codes(d):
    result = {}
    for key, val in d.items():
        for i in range(len(val)):
            ch = val[i]
            if ch not in result:
                result[ch] = {key: [i]}
            else:
                result[ch][key] = result[ch].get(key, []) + [i]
    return result

def get_code(ch, char_codes):
    key = random.sample(char_codes[ch].keys(), 1)[0]
    char_pos = random.choice(char_codes[ch][key])
    code = '{}.{}'.format(key, char_pos)
    return code

char_codes = build_char_codes(dictionary)

given_string = 'You are what you eat.'
codes = [get_code(ch, char_codes) for ch in given_string]

print(' '.join(codes))
```

Notes:

- char_codes index all possible choices of each character in the dictionary
- it sample all the key in dictionary first (uniformly random), and then it sample the position in the string (uniformly random). But it is not sampling uniformly among all the possible choices of a character.

Comment: I tried similar way, but memory is issued. Thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 1):

In preparation for the transformation, you could create a dictionary with each letter in the ICD description mapping to a list of codes that contain it at various indexes.

Then, the transformation process would simply be a matter of picking one of the code.index from the entry in the dictionary for each letter in the given string:

preparation ...

```
with open(fileName,'r') as f:
    icd        = [line.split(" ",1) for line in f.read().split("\n")]
    icdLetters = dict() # list of ICD codes with index for each possible letter
    for code,description in icd:
        for i,letter in enumerate(description):
            icdLetters.setdefault(letter,[]).append(f"{code}.{i}")
```

transformation....

```
import random
given_string = 'You are what you eat.'
result       = [ random.choice(icdLetters.get(c,["-"])) for c in given_string ]
```

output:

```
print(result)

['A66.0', 'T80.22.35', 'S53.136.34', 'C40.90.33', 'S53.136.43', 'Z96.621.12', 'B57.30.24', 'H59.121.55', 'V14.1.43', 'S93.121.47', 'H59.121.9', 'V04.92.17', 'T80.22.80', 'O16.1.22', 'T25.61.10', 'S53.136.34', 'F44.6.32', 'M67.232.29', 'M89.771.34', 'S93.121.7', 'Z68.36.29']
```

If you want to save some memory, your dictionary could store indexes in the main list of icd codes and descriptions instead of the formatted values:

```
with open(fileName,'r') as f:
    icd        = [line.split(" ",1) for line in f.read().split("\n")]
    icdLetters = dict() 
    for codeIndex,(code,description) in enumerate(icd):
        for letterIndex,letter in enumerate(description):
            icdLetters.setdefault(letter,[]).append((codeIndex,letterIndex))

import random
def letterToCode(letter):
    if letter not in icdLetters: return "-"
    codeIndex,letterIndex = random.choice(icdLetters[letter])
    return f"{icd[codeIndex][0]}.{letterIndex}"


given_string = 'You are what you eat.'
result       = [ letterToCode(c) for c in given_string ]
```

Comment: thank you I was about to looking for way to save memory :) it was really helpful.